# Robot Framework run autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey, robotframework

How to run autohotkey script from Robot Framework ?

Comment: What is your question? Have you answered your own question within the question itself?

Comment: Hi Goralight, exactly. I wanted to help to others. there was no such an answer before.

Comment: Id recommend that you answer you own question then :) What you have done is great. But split your question. The `How do I run Autohotkey on RF?` in the question part, and then below you can answer it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for this positive comment. I follow it. :)

Comment: Many thanks for "Tuks" and "Todor" comments and suggestions. I approved them!

Answer (score 4):

One solution:

1. Add the `Process` library to the Settings section of the robotframework file.

This allows robotframework to run local OS executables like autohotkey.exe:

```
Library           Process
```

2. Use the `Run Process` keyword in your script.
   (The trick is to put an extra backslashes before all

   - "backslashes" and
   - "space"

   (but don't add to ":" ). This is to escape them in robotframework source, and preserve for the execution.

---

```
Run Process    c:\\Program\ Files\\AutoHotkey\\AutoHotkey.exe    C:\\work\\robot\\S2\\URS_download.ahk
```

---

[image]